# Firebase not accessing files outside public folder

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am just getting started with firebase hosting. I was able to deploy the website and everything, but for my index.html file to access my css, js, and other html files, they all need to be in the /public directory. Originally, all these files were outside of /public and I had just used ../ to access them from the /public directory, but firebase hosting wont recognize it. Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's the way it works.  The CLI will only deploy the files present in the public folder.  It's not possible to make it deploy files from any other location.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart):

> **Specify a directory to use as your public root directory.**
>
> This directory contains all your publicly served static files, including your index.html file and any other assets that you want to deploy to Firebase Hosting.